# nginx rewrite rule php melody

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I am using nginx. I want to rewrite urls. My code:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$ /watch.php?vid=$2 last;
```

Example of url:
http://104.238.130.170/hudson-against-the-grain-video_14a4e06f8.html

But when I save file then restarts nginx server i got error:

```
[emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:46
```

QUESTION: What is wrong on my rewrite rule?

```
rewrite ^/([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$ /watch.php?vid=$2 last;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly brackets `{9}`are most likely giving a problem in your regex. Surround the rule with quotes like below and try it.

```
rewrite "^/([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$" /watch.php?vid=$2 last;
```

> Note: for curly braces( { and } ), as they are used both in regexes
>   and for block control, to avoid conflicts, regexes with curly braces
>   are to be enclosed with double quotes (or single quotes).

More info [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)